# Android: How to switch between activites properly with navigation drawer and child activity

Tags: android

Basically I came across a problem that I do not even know how to search / look up So I will try to explain it as best I can in as little words as possible.

In the project I am working on, I have a sliding/navigation Drawer(MainScreenActivity) that I use to switch fragments without using new activties. However, when I click a menu button in the action bar I go to a  new activity which lists notifications of people " checked in ". The user than has the option to accept the "check in" by clicking a button. When the button is clicked, this should directly go to one of the navigation/sliding drawer Fragments and bring it up.  How do you go about doing this.

If there is any confusion I can try to clarify it.... Thanks

Navigation/Sliding Drawer"Record"Fragment (MainScreenActivity) - > (NotificationActivity) - > "Record" Fragment" (MainScreenActivity)

Answer (score 1):

The common way to approach this issue is to create listeners in your activity and within your fragment you can use:

```
YourActivity.class.cast(getActivity()).calltheListenerForThatFragment();
```

You can add different listeners for the different fragments that might need to call the activity or one single listener that takes an int as parameter:

```
YourActivity.class.cast(getActivity()).callGenericListener(fragmentId);
```

In this case you can make a switch in your activity listener and separate the functionality depending on the fragment that called it.

Hope it Helps!

Regards!